# Operation of a p'-group on a set of p-power order and fix points

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, associative-algebras, separable-algebras

The question is related to Taft's Theorem about G-invariant radical complements. Let $A$ be an associative unitary finite-dimensional $K$-Algebra posessing a separable factor Algebra by ist nilradical. Suppose $G$ is a finite group such that the order of $G$ is not divisible by the characteristic of $K$ and $G$ is acting on $A$ as auto- or anti-automorphism. Taft has proven that a $G$-invariant radical complement exists. A $G$-invariant radical complement is a fix point of the set of all radical complements under the Action of $G$.

If we assume a finite field, then one can prove that the number of radical complements is a power of the characteristic of $K$. A natural question is:

Let $G$ be a finite $p'$-Group acting on a set $M$ of $p$-power order. Is there a fix Point in $M$ under $G$?

Within $S_3$ one can construct examples of a subgroup of order 2 acting on the cosets of $S_3$ Modulo another subgroup of order 2 -- which is a set containg 3 elements. Within this example no fix Point exist.

My questions are:

1.) What is so Special within the mentioned situation that a fix point exists.

2.) Is there a General result on fix Points related to the described context?

Comment: In your $S_3$-example, there is a fixed point? In fact, when $G$ is a $q$-group ($q$ prime) acting on a set $M$, then the number of fixed points in $M$ under $G$ is congruent to the size of $M$ modulo $q$. So when $\lvert M \rvert$ is coprime to $q$, then fixed points exists. The situation is different when $\lvert G \rvert $ is divisible by at least two different primes. An example would be a group $G$ of order $6$ acting on a set with $5$ elements, with one orbit of length $2$ and one of length $3$.

Comment: Thanks for both comments. I thought maybe ist related to the fact that the radical complements are conjugated under the p-group $1+rad(A)$ and that $G$ is also acting on these "conjugation" elements. But I can't see/find a general argumentation for this fact.

Comment: Malcev had results of this nature too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the guess in your comment is correct: There is the following result of Glauberman:

> **Theorem** (Glauberman). Let the finite group $G$ act on the finite group $N$ by automorphisms, where $(\lvert G \rvert, \lvert N \rvert ) = 1$. Let both $G$ and $N$ on a set $\Omega$, where the action of $N$ is transitive, and the compability condition 
>   $$ (\omega n) g = (\omega g) n^g \quad \text{for all } 
>    \omega\in \Omega,\, n\in N,\, g\in G $$
>   holds. Then $\Omega$ has a fixed point under $G$. Moreover, $C_N(G)$ acts transitively on the $G$-fixed points.

In your situation, this lemma applies with $N = 1 + \operatorname{rad}(A)$, which acts transitively on the set of complements of the radical, if I understand correctly.

Glauberman's result appears as Lemma 3.24 in Isaacs's text on finite groups or in Glauberman's original paper (Theorem 4).

*Isaacs, I. Martin*, Finite group theory. Graduate Studies in Mathematics 92. AMS 2008. [ZBL1169.20001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1169.20001).
*Glauberman, George*, [**Fixed points in groups with operator groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01117119), Math. Z. 84, 120-125 (1964). [ZBL0123.02601](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0123.02601).

Comment: Interestingly, the proof in these sources depends on knowing that at least one of $G$ and $N$ is solvable. This in turn is justified by quoting the Odd Order Theorem of Feit and Thompson.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But in the particular situation of the question, we know that $N$ is nilpotent (in fact a $p$-group).

Comment: Yes, fair enough.

Comment: Taft has enhanced this theorem within his article Earl J. Taft, Orthogonai Conjugacies in Finite Groups, Math. Annalen 170, 37-40, 1967.